# Compiled wireshark 1.10.0 presents an uncomplete interface in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: unity, gtk

I compiled Wireshark 1.10.0 in my Ubuntu 12.04 but it presents an incomplete user interface like in this image (the missing part is at the bottom).

[image]

This seems to be something wrong with Unity because when i disable 'Ubuntu unity plugin' in CCSM this problem disappeared.Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed the problem by unselect the 'save window size' option in Preferences->User Interface. 
Still have no idea why this happen and I'm considering to report a bug to the Wireshark team.